# Value Objects and API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, domain-driven-design

Is it ok to use Value Objects as API contrancts? In this case, there may be difficulties with serialization/deserialization.

```
public IActionResult Post(ValueObject contract)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Or it is better to use some simple objects and map them to Value Object in controller action method?

```
public IActionResult Post(ObjectContract contract)
{
    var valueObject = _mapper.Map(contract);
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: What is ValueObject and ObjectContract ? can you give some examples.

Comment: It is better to use mapped objects for API's that way you can assign other useful data to that object based on different scenarios.

Comment: API not always returns an object you need to code in a way so it cares for other expected cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is OK. Your API contract will be more explicit, your controller actions less verbose and your parsing or deserialization logic will be in a single place for each type. In order to instruct Web API how to deserialize your value objects you'll have to create custom [Model Binders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#model-binders)